# Auto subscribe a user when signing up to app

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, chat, subscription

This is so interesting question, I think. I am developing a chat application using xmpp in google go. Upon testing, I could not send chat message to a google user unless that user would add my app as contact or initiate the chat session via gtalk/chat at his gmail account. Is it possible to subscribe the user to my app when he signup for membership in my app? User service does not have any properties for this nor a hash or code or cookie for me to store and know that this user has approved sending chat from the app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The user has to give explicit permission to add your bot to their contact list; simply signing in is not enough.